How to Find the Coordinate Transformation for a PDE with a Symmetric Positive Definite Matrix Coefficient in 2D?
I am studying a partial differential equation of the form:
$\forall\boldsymbol{x}:\nabla_{\boldsymbol{x}}\cdot\left(A(\boldsymbol{x})\cdot\nabla_{\boldsymbol{x}}f(\boldsymbol{x})\right)=g(\boldsymbol{x}),$
where $\boldsymbol{x}$ is an n-dimensional real column vector in a well-behaved real domain, $A_{ij}(\boldsymbol{x})$ are elements of a symmetric, positive definite matrix $A$, and $f$ and $g$ are scalar functions.
I found that under a coordinate transformation $\boldsymbol{y}(\boldsymbol{x})$ with inverse $\boldsymbol{x}(\boldsymbol{y})$, with Jacobian elements $J_{ij}(\boldsymbol{x})=\partial y_{i}(\boldsymbol{x})/\partial x_{j}$, the PDE transforms as follows:
$\forall\boldsymbol{y}:\left|\mathrm{det}J(\boldsymbol{x}(\boldsymbol{y}))\right|\nabla_{\boldsymbol{y}}\cdot\left(\frac{J^{T}(\boldsymbol{x}(\boldsymbol{y}))\cdot A(\boldsymbol{x}(\boldsymbol{y}))\cdot J(\boldsymbol{x}(\boldsymbol{y}))}{\left|\mathrm{det}J(\boldsymbol{x}(\boldsymbol{y}))\right|}\cdot\nabla_{\boldsymbol{y}}f(\boldsymbol{x}(\boldsymbol{y}))\right)=g(\boldsymbol{x}(\boldsymbol{y})).$
Given that $A_{ij}(\boldsymbol{x})$ is symmetric and positive definite, it seems like $A$ is related to a metric tensor. Therefore, a coordinate transformation should exist that simplifies the PDE to a Poisson equation. I'm trying to find such a transformation.
In other words, I'm looking for the Jacobian $J(\boldsymbol{x})$ that satisfies:
$\frac{J^{T}(\boldsymbol{x}(\boldsymbol{y}))\cdot A(\boldsymbol{x}(\boldsymbol{y}))\cdot J(\boldsymbol{x}(\boldsymbol{y}))}{\left|\mathrm{det}J(\boldsymbol{x}(\boldsymbol{y}))\right|}=I,$
where $I$ is the identity matrix.
I found that since $A$ is symmetric, it can be diagonalized by an orthogonal matrix $Q(\boldsymbol{x})$, such that $A(\boldsymbol{x})=Q(\boldsymbol{x})\Lambda(\boldsymbol{x})Q^{T}(\boldsymbol{x})$, where $\Lambda(\boldsymbol{x})$ is a diagonal matrix containing positive eigenvalues $\lambda_{i}(\boldsymbol{x})$. Then, the following matrix $J(\boldsymbol{x})$ seems to satisfy the transformation condition:
$J(\boldsymbol{x})=Q(\boldsymbol{x})\Lambda(\boldsymbol{x})^{-1/2}\left(\prod_{i=1}^{n}\sqrt{\lambda_{i}(\boldsymbol{x})}\right)^{\frac{1}{n-2}}.$
This expression works well, except when $n=2$, where the division by $n-2$ leads to a problem.
My question: What am I missing here? How can this transformation be adapted or modified to work in the case where $n=2$? Is there an alternative approach to solving this problem for $n=2$? I tried using a Cholesky decomposition instead, but ran into the same problem.

I learned now that when $n=2$, the determinant of the following quantity necessarily equals the determinant of $A(\boldsymbol{x}(\boldsymbol{y}))$:
$\mathrm{det}\left(\frac{J^{T}(\boldsymbol{x}(\boldsymbol{y}))\cdot A(\boldsymbol{x}(\boldsymbol{y}))\cdot J(\boldsymbol{x}(\boldsymbol{y}))}{\left|\mathrm{det}J(\boldsymbol{x}(\boldsymbol{y}))\right|}\right)=\mathrm{det}A(\boldsymbol{x}(\boldsymbol{y})).$
Consequently, it seems like the question can only be answered when $\mathrm{det}A=1$. Then, one can simply use $J(\boldsymbol{x})=Q(\boldsymbol{x})\Lambda(\boldsymbol{x})^{-1/2}$.
Otherwise, no such transformation appears to exist.
